# CardLayout - positioning components

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, cardlayout

Is there any way to tell a `JPanel` using `CardLayout` where to add a component?

Let' s say I have one of these panels in the center of a frame, and I want to display 3 components inside that panel. Would this be possible?

Comment: Well i have to display actual playing cards, that are on top of eachother. You should be able to drag them around and stuffs like that, but when i try to add multiple playing card objects (which are JLabels) to the JPanel using CardLayout only 1 card appears ( since i can't position them inside the panel). Do you think another layout-manager would be better for this task? I was also thinking about using LayeredPanels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's easy. Just put a `JPanel` as one of the cards, then position the components in the panel using whatever layout works best.